# how to select a child div of this in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I select a child div of "this" in jquery
then apply toggle to it,
and at the same time disable the link effect that handles the click event?

here is the html:

```
<a href="#" class="title">Link</a>   
<div class="data"> content here </div>
<a href="#" class="title">Link</a>    
<div class="data">
    content here
</div>
```

here is my jquery code:

```
$('a.title').each(function(event){  

    var selection = $(this).find('.data');

    $(this).click(function(event){
        $(div).toggle();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I changed it to this and it worked:

```
$('a.title').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(event){
        var selection = $(this).parent().children('.data');
        $(selection).toggle();
        event.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Comment: i miss typed it should be event.preventDefault();

Comment: `$(this).find('.data')` wont work in your `each` loop because `div` is out of scope with respect to `a.title`

Comment: What do you mean by child div?

Comment: Replace `.find('.data')` with `.next('.data')` http://api.jquery.com/next/

Comment: In the example you've given, the `div` is not a child of the `a` element. It's a sibling.

Comment: Please don't update your question to include your solution. Either accept the answer that was most helpful, or if none really helped but you came up with something else on your own then post your own answer and accept it. Note also you don't need the `.each()`. Just say `$('a.title').click(...` and your click handler will be bound to all matching elements.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$('a.title').click(function(event){

    var $selection = $(this).next('.data');
    event.preventDefault();
    $selection.toggle();              

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a.title').on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.data').toggle();
});​
```

Comment: @A.K - I think this is a quality answer which fully answers the question, but I'm not sure what you mean by "comprehensive." It's the shortest answer (which isn't necessarily bad, of course) and offers no explanation of the code.

Comment: It should be pretty self explanatory, if not there's a great [API](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) over at the jQuery site where the OP can read about all the different functions till his eyes water up.

Comment: I know, and I'm not trying to insult your answer in any way. "Comprehensive" just sounded like a poor/confusing word choice to me.

Comment: If you could count on people to read the jQuery API doco then 75% (if not more) of the jQuery questions on SO wouldn't have been posted in the first place. (Not that I'm saying that applies to this question.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you after soemthing like this

http://jsfiddle.net/pVKcm/1/

```
$('a.title').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.data').toggle();
});​
```

Comment: interesting? why did my answer got -1, any reasons

Comment: thank you man this is the one I need, though i finf the second link not working I tweaked it a bit and it works:

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an `each()` function, jQuery applies the event to all matched elements. Also, your `div` elements are not children of your `a` elements. To select the next `div` element, however, you could use the `next()` function:

```
$('a.title').click(function(event){
    var selection = $(this).next('.data');
    selection.toggle(); 

    event.preventDefault();       
});
```